# linker cannot find dlsym

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to compile a C++ program in Linux Mint 17 using Qt 5.3.0. I have added the following line into .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -ldl -fPIC
```

My program uses dlsym, but the linker cannot find it. Here's the error message:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

How can I link my program?

Comment: @FinalContest I tried, but now it complains it can't find -ld. Weird, otherwise my Qt installation seems to be working fine, I can build example projects etc.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, you should use `LIBS += -ldl -fPIC`.

Comment: whoops, I should have caught that typo myself. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use the `LIBS` variable for this rather than the `QMAKE_LFLAGS` as follows:

```
LIBS += -ldl -fPIC
```